# duplicate table

Tags: sql

error when duplicate table

CREATE TABLE ZMMM_END1 LIKE ZMMM_END

CREATE TABLE ZMMM_END1 LIKE ZMMM_END
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:
*Action:

CREATE TABLE ZMMM_END1 LIKE ZMMM_END
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: What kind of sql implementation you are using? MySql?

Comment: I guess you are using Oracle and the problem is that you are trying to use MySql syntax in Oracle

Comment: Its just seem to be an oracle database  for duplicating the table you can use CREATE TABLE ZMMM_END1 AS SELECT * FROM ZMMM_END; this statement and if you only want to copy the structure without data you can use CREATE TABLE ZMMM_END1 AS SELECT * FROM ZMMM_END WHERE 1=0; it will create the same structure as the original one

Comment: and your mistake is 'like'  in oracle you cannot use like  you have to use `CREATE TABLE AS` statement